# Aggregating Objects , need help/explanation

Tags: php, class, object

I have wrote this code by looking at similar code from a PHP cookbook. I have few troubles with executing and understanding it + it is not working well. Hope someone can help me.

```html
<?php

class example {
//protected $a;
//protected $c;

public function NumberInput($number){
 $this->a = $number;
   }


public function NumberOutput(){
  return $this->a;
   }
}


class example2 {

 public function __construct(){
 
  $this->mergingclass = new example;
  }

 public function numberInput2($number){
 $this->c = $number;
    }

 public function NumberOutput2(){
  return $this->c;
  }

   public function __call($method,$arguments){
    echo "called methos is $method <br> ";
     ;
    return $this->x = $arguments;
  }     
    
    



 }


$b = new example2;
$b->NumberInput(7);
echo $b->NumberOutput();


?>
```

so my questions are:

1. Why do I even need __construct function ? Code is working excatly the same with or without it. Or atleast I can't spot the difference with my newbie abilities. If I understand correctly it should agreggate objects but when I put it in comments nothing changes.
2. When I execute this code insted of number 7 I get "Array". I suppose number 7 is inside of that array, so how can I echo it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So `__construct` function do 'something' at first when the object is created (just like initializing the object) and to use/access the member variables first they must be declare

Answer (score 0):

First of all, __construct is like a magic method in PHP, that makes it possible to create an object out of class. Each time you write something like this:`$myObject = new Object();` constructor of Object class is called by default and it creates object referenced by $myObject variable. So without that method in it, you will not be able to properly use classes and create objects.

use `print_r($array)` or `var_dump($array)` to see array structure